# Python getattr() with another attribute as the default

Tags: python, object, getattr

I have two classes. One class has an attribute `x` but not `y`, and the other class has an attribute `y` but not `x`.

I have a function that accepts either class as an argument. Is there a one-line way to assign a new variable to the `x` attribute if it exists, or the `y` attribute if not? I.e.,

```
if hasattr(input_object, 'x'):
    new_var = input_object.x
else:
    new_var = input_object.y
```

I thought I would be able to do:

```
new_var = getattr(input_object, 'x', input_object.y)
```

But that raises an `AttributeError` if the `input_object` doesn't have `y`, even though it does have `x`.

Comment: What's wrong with your existing solution with the if/else?

Comment: Nothing I guess - I'm doing this for a few different attribute pairs and I wanted to cut down on how many checks I have to do before I can just assign the values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or you can use an if/else construct:

```
new_var = (
  input_object.x if hasattr(input_object, 'x')
  else input_object.y
)
```

This will not evaluate `input_object.y` *unless* there is no
`input_object.x`.

Comment: The advantage here is that you will still get an AttributeError for `input_object.y` if it does not exist AND `input_object.x` does not exist, if that is the behavior you want.  utku.zih's answer will never raise an AttributeError, which is fine as long as you can do something sane with `None` or other static default.

Comment: No need to use `getattr` for `'x'`, you can do `input_object.x` just as you did for `y`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `getattr` for `y` too.

```
new_var = getattr(input_object, 'x', None) or getattr(input_object, 'y', None)
```

Comment: Note that this may cause unexpected results if 'x' is explicitly set to None, or to any other boolean-false value (like zero).

Comment: @BrenBarn, good point. I would go for an answer similar to larsks: ```input_object.x if hasattr(input_object,"x") else input_object.y```

Answer (score 0):

Nest the getattr call like so:

```
getattr(model, "field1", getattr(model, "field2", None))
```